# Run NUnit Tests in VS2012 Continuous Build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit, build-system

If *anyone* knows the correct spell to make NUnit tests run when in the Continuous build in 2012 I'd love to hear what it is.

I have scoured Google and found lots of articles like [this one](http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/72-running-nunit-tests-from-team-foundation-server-2012-continuous-integration-build) and I've carried out the steps it suggested I needed. I battled with the Build refusing to find nunit.framework.dll and finally got it to build. Only when it built it ignored all of the tests 'cos it would only look for and run MSTest tests :-(

I would really appreciate any pointers on how I modify the workflow to look for and execute NUnit tests.